# How to share and specialize base models in different Django applications?

Tags: python, django, django-models

We are developing a collection management project using Django, usable for different types of collections.

This problem quite naturally divides itself in two:

- The common part, that will be shared by all collections.
- The specializations, different for each collection type.

### Example

To illustrate this a bit further, let's take a simplified example in **pseudocode**.

#### Common part

```
class ItemBase: # ideally abstract
    name = CharField()

class Rental
    item = ForeignKey("Item")
    rented_to_person = CharField()
```

#### Specialization for a collection of cars

```
class ItemSpecialization
    horse_power = Int()
```

### The problem

The question is how we could organize the code in order to allow reuse of the common part without duplicating its content ?

We would imagine it would be best to have the common part as a **non**-installed application, and have each specialized configuration as a separate **installed** application. But this would cause a problem with the `Rental` concrete class, because it resides in the common-part application.

Any advices on how we could proceed ?

Comment: Why cannot you make it an installed app with concrete classes instead of abstract classes (as non-installed mean these will be abstract classes)? And add this app to all your Django applciations?

Comment: What do you mean by "add this app to all your Django applciations" ? If I install the Common-part, it will install a separate `ItemBase` model. If I make this model abstract (and derive `ItemSpecialization` form it), I cannot refer to the Item from `Rental`

Comment: Why not make a separate app for Rental ?

Comment: @AdN then you can make all the classes in base common part abstract and then it will be must for your specialized apps to inherit all the abstract classes in common no matter you want to use them as is or add/override the functionality in parent abstract classes

Comment: @MuhammadTahir That is a clever trick indeed ! Is not there another way to make a table for a model defined in another app, than this abstract in appA, concrete in appB trick ?

Comment: @AdN You can specify app_name in Meta class of Rental to consider Rental in app_name. But it will be a bad approach. First your common will be strongly coupled with your app_name. Second what if you want to subclass Rental in your one app but not other, then will the Rental be abstract or concrete?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want, you may use an [abstract  model class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) for common stuff, and inherit from that in specialized model classes.

Otherwise, if you really want one table for all common data, typically to be able to relate to it, then you'll need your specialized model to have a relation to the common model. It can be a [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships), or you can use [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance), in which case the foreign key in question will be managed for you by django, but it'll be harder to use.

Comment: Actually, I strongly prefer to avoid having one separate table for common data. But if I make `ItemBase` abstract, then what should `Rental` refer to ?

Comment: define "refer to" please

Comment: That's why you need a table for your common stuff. Otherwise, use a generic many to many relation, ie. with django-gm2m or django-generic-m2m, note that it's a bit hard too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a `OneToOneField` field relationship. Based on your example:

```
class ItemBase:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Rental:
    item = models.OneToOneField(ItemBase)
    rented_to_person = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ItemSpecialization
    item = models.OneToOneField(ItemBase)
    horse_power = models.IntegerField()
```

With this model hierarchy, you could fetch Rental or ItemSpecialzation objects and also gain access to ItemBase fields. It's basically OO inheritance for Django models. More details in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/